# How can I free a growable (using realloc) dynamic array within a struct?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-management, free

I'm revisiting C after quite a long break, and have been utilising growable arrays specifically to help me get back into manual memory management. I use modified code from, and credit to, [University of Exeter](https://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/resources/jmr/appendix-growable.html)).

I'm trying to free the individually allocated elements from an (in this case integer) array within a struct, but am having trouble in doing so.

First, I create a struct to hold an integer array, the current number of elements, and the buffer size to keep track of allocated memory.

```
typedef struct int_array
{
    int *values;
    int numValues;
    int bufferLen;
} IntArray;
```

The initial struct is then created using the following:

```
IntArray *new_int_array(void)
{
    IntArray *intArr;

    intArr = calloc(1, sizeof *intArr);
    intArr->bufferLen = intArr->numValues = 0;
    intArr->values = NULL;

    return intArr;
}
```

Finally, to add elements to the array:

```
void add_element_to_array(IntArray *intArr, int 
    values)
{
    // Check to see if array extension needed
    if (intArr->numValues == intArr->bufferLen) {
        intArr->bufferLen += GROWBY; // #define GROWBY 16
        intArr->values = realloc
            (intArr->values, intArr->bufferLen * 
                sizeof intArr->values);
    }

    intArr->values[intArr->numValues] = 
        values;
    intArr->numValues++;
}
```

I'm used to freeing a single-malloc'd/calloc'd array, but from what I have read looping through all elements and freeing each one (one free per one allocation) would be the correct way of going about it, but I can't seem to get it right. I'm calling a helper function to free the memory:

```
void free_struct(IntArray *intArr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < intArr->bufferLen; i++){
        free(intArr->values[i]);
    }
}
```

I could paste in the numerous errors I get while playing around with the above free_struct function, but I'd be here forever. They range from expecting void * to invalid type arguments, to double frees and others beside.

**EDIT:** I neglected to mention the biggest issue I faced, and that was a memory leak according to Valgrind. The accepted answer solved the problem, as correctly dereferencing `intArr->values` allowed me to free the same `intArr->values` and then `intArr` itself.

Comment: Too much information is always better than too less. Post the errors you got, including the ```main``` function.

Comment: Aside: Check the return value of ```calloc``` and ```realloc.```

Comment: `sizeof intArr->values` is not what you want. `free(intArr->values[i]);` cannot possibly be right since `intArr->values[i]` is not a pointer. Try finding a pointer (or pointers) on that line.

Comment: Right @Haris, so that's one of the potential errors I get, relating to the return type of realloc: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’. Which makes sense to me, although I don't expect I can recast to void * here?

Comment: @n.m for sure, intArr is itself a pointer, as is intArr->values. In freeing intArr->values, I seem to get a memory leak, which is why I approached the problem using a loop which is clearly wrong.

Comment: "I seem to get a memory leak" how do you know? Post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. Valgrind said I was short of frees vs. allocations. The sizeof pointer issue resolved, and thus freeing intArr->values and then intArr itself, solved the problem.

Comment: Valgrind should tell you where you have allocate things that you forgot to free. We cannot, because we don't get to see a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem in this code when adding:

```
if (intArr->numValues == intArr->bufferLen) {
    intArr->bufferLen += GROWBY; // #define GROWBY 16
    intArr->values = realloc
        (intArr->values, intArr->bufferLen *
            sizeof intArr->values);
}
```

This is on the way toward the fix:

```
if( arr->nVal == arr->bufLen) {
    arr->bufLen += GROWBY; // #define GROWBY 16
    arr->vals = realloc( arr->vals, arr->bufLen * sizeof *arr->vals );
                                            // NOTICE    ^
}
```

The OP code lacked a dereferencing asterisk in the `sizeof` term of the expression.

Notice how much easier this is to read when an *involved* statement is not spread across multiple lines of source code. I recommend using meaningful-but-short variable names. Source code needs to be 'scannable', not 'readable beside the fire on a winter's evening.'

Notice that the size of an element is the size of an integer, not a pointer. This will become important when the stored integers change to stored structs.

There's usually no alternative, when that `alloc` family fail in their task but to exit gracefully. To continue processing with a NULL pointer (until a crash) is not graceful.

```
if( arr->nVal == arr->bufLen) {
    arr->bufLen += GROWBY; // #define GROWBY 16
    arr->vals = realloc( arr->vals, arr->bufLen * sizeof *arr->vals );
    if( arr->vals == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "realloc() failure\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

Now that that is cleared up, the 'free()` problem should be easier to understand.

The one pointer to the array points at a single contiguous block of memory. You only need one `free( arr->vals );` to release the entire block.

While this 'grows' the array in increments of `GROWBY`, you might want to experiment with removing a random element (involving shifting subsequent elements upward in the array; see `memmove()`) and even shrinking the array (`realloc()` again) when there are `SHRINKBY` unused elements at the bottom of the array...

**EDIT:**
Because `calloc()` guarantees the allocated bytes will be set to 0, this:

```
IntArray *new_int_array(void)
{
    IntArray *intArr;

    intArr = calloc(1, sizeof *intArr);
    intArr->bufferLen = intArr->numValues = 0;
    intArr->values = NULL;

    return intArr;
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
IntArray *new_int_array(void)
{
    IntArray *arr = calloc(1, sizeof *arr);
    if( arr == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "calloc() failed\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Aha, yes the lack of dereference could be a problem (concerning that the linked article makes the same error). The single free (on arr->vals) causes me a problem I experienced prior to looking at a looped free function: memory leaks. Valgrind finds lost bytes. The only pointers I'm using are related to a file and the struct/array, so the free issue can only relate to the struct/array.

Comment: As a second comment to avoid making the first one become too long, I shall definitely have a look into removing elements and shrinking the array, that'll be a very useful learning experience, thanks.

Comment: @ Fe2O3, "Source code needs to be 'scannable', not 'readable beside the fire on a winter's evening.'" This made me chuckle, thanks for that. I see different sides of the argument for variable names, either being short for readability or long and descriptive for the same. However...I'm coding to a column width of 60 and so your approach would work better in this regard. It's something I should really ditch, and only still do so thanks to my university C lecturer back in the day who insisted on a width of 60, and possibly even C90 if memory serves correctly. I need to break out of that mindset.

Comment: The sizeof may just be wasteful (and deceptive), measuring 8bytes for a pointer instead of 4bytes for an integer (depending on your system). It will be a problem if you start trying to store 42byte structs in the 8bytes space of a pointer. re: "naming vars". I learned C from the K&R Bible "The C Programming Language". "Brevity is the soul of wit", it is said... And, less to type/read means one can consider the logic, not the eloquence of the code. Why do people use 'i' & 'j' as in `arr[ i ][ j `] when they mean `arr[ r ][ c ]` ... as in 'row' & 'col'? Always gets me!!

Comment: Thanks for the edit to your response; my mistake for not realising calloc zeroes the allocated bytes (I knew this, but didn't think to remove the next line...that'll teach me for modifying code rather than entirely rewriting). I see your point regarding sizeof; using your 42byte example, what is the best approach? As someone who writes better than codes, brevity is truly my nemesis...but perhaps I should relearn C from my K&R 2e. `arr[ r ][ c ]` would be far too sensible, even compared to what I always used: `arr[ row ][ col ]`. I've never understood i, j, k etc. for loops or otherwise.

Comment: re: future version with "42 byte struct" (instead of `int`): If you always take the `sizeof` the object the pointer points at, you'll do fine. eg: the pointer wants to point to a large struct? Using `sizeof *ptr` will deliver the right size... re: 'i' & 'j': I believe this is a _holdover_ from Fortran. Variables named with 1st letter being 'I' thru 'N' would default to being integers (not floats)... C isn't Fortran, but the habit remains...